# Execute and Return from Code Block (after Elvis operator)

Tags: kotlin

I am really not sure how to name the title, hence I am going to explain it as best as I can:

```
val a = b ?: ({
    val temp = c.evaluate()
    store(temp)
    temp // returns temp to the lambda, which will set `a` to `temp` if `b` is null 
})()
```

<sup>**1**: what works, what I currently use</sup>

This works fine, but what I ideally want to do is just using the code block and not passing the lambda to a function (`({})`) and then evaluating it. In my imagination, it would look something like this:

```
val a = b ?: {
    val temp = c.evaluate()
    store(temp)
    temp // returns temp to the lambda, which will set `a` to `temp` if `b` is null 
}
```

<sup>**2**: what I would like to have</sup>

The above does *not* work. I am actually just looking for a better way to write <sup>1</sup>.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) function:

```
val a = b ?: run {
    val temp = c.evaluate()
    store(temp)
    temp
}
```

Comment: I'd add a link to the documentation https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) function:

```
val a = b ?: c.evaluate().also { store(it) }
```

This allows you to do something with a value while passing that value as the result of the `also`